# Silverlight databound image displayed inside tooltip

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, tooltip

this question is a follow up from this one. [silverlight 4 image preview from tooltip on datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726428/silverlight-4-image-preview-from-tooltip-on-datagrid)

This is my new problem, I have been trying to get a tool tip to pop up with the preview of the document that is returned in search results of my silverlight app.  I have linked the image and it comes up with the correct image, however it opens in a new or separate window instead of the tooltip itself.  Here is my code behind..

```
private void PPTImageToolTip(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string docname = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext.ToString();
        string baseUri = "http://localhost:58904/ShowDocument.aspx?DocumentName=" + docname + "-ppt" + "&type=jpg";
        var hostingWindow = HtmlPage.Window;
        hostingWindow.Navigate(new Uri(baseUri, UriKind.Absolute), "_parent");
    }
```

This is set to go to my ShowDocument.aspx page which handles this operation..

```
else if (File.Exists(strFullFilePath) && sType == "jpg")
                    {
                        fileStream = new FileStream(strFullFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                        fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));
                        try
                        {
                            Response.ClearHeaders();
                            Response.ClearContent();
                            Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        { }
                    }
```

I realize that it transfers to another 'page' but I have not been able to get that image or that page to show up in the tool tip itself instead of populating the new window.  Is this because of my HtmlPage.window code? Or because the ShowDocument.aspx page is already called and it cant call back? Is there a workable solution to get the image to populate inside the tool tip? Or is there a way to repsonse.redirect into the silverlight control that holds the tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to display the image inside the tooltip (and not in the html window), the following will work:

First the web service (ashx)

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        String fileName = @"c:\PathToMyFile\Myfile.jpg";
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to call the service from the Silverlight client:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                using (Stream stream = e.Result)
                {
                    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                    img.SetSource(stream);

                    // Update MyImage.Source. Use the Dispatcher to ensure this happens on the UI Thread
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            MyImage.Source = img;
                        });

                }
            };
        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(String.Format(BaseURL + "MyHandler.ashx")));
    }
}
```

And finally the xaml for the view:

```
<Border x:Name="MyBorder" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Black">
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <Image x:Name="MyImage" />
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>

</Border>
```

Comment: i marked this as an answer because it set me in the right direction but Im confused about the line //Must set MyImage.Source on the UI thread' part? What do I need to do for that part?

Comment: If you try to set `MyImage.Source = img;` without using the Dispatcher, you will get a cross thread access exception. So you don't need to do anything more than the sample, just don't remove the Dispatcher bit. I've updated my answer to clarify this.

Comment: OK i played around with that and eventually found that out, but my main problem now is that my 'MyImage' is nested deep within my grid and the code-behind is unable to find it, only able to find the column that it is in.

Comment: You will be able to setup and invoke the WebClient from within your loaded event handler. So instead of hostingWindow etc, use the WebClient. The Image instance you need is the sender.

Comment: So after trying a couple scenarios, I was unable to get this working. I could not find the MyImage from the codebehind. And there was a strange error from the invoke, something about lambda expression?